# Is it possible to pass the inserted / deleted / updated table from a trigger to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I am not sure if this is possible or not ? I am looking for an example of passing the inserted / delete / updated table from a trigger to a stored procedure.

Note: I want to add this trigger to all tables in the database and I don't want to have to rewrite / generate the trigger for each individual table.

This way if the table changes the trigger does not need to be changed as well.

e.g. something like this :

```
   CREATE TRIGGER [schema].[myTable_myTrigger] ON [schema].[myTable]
AFTER INSERT,
    INSERT,
    DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tableAfterChange TABLE 
    DECLARE @tableBeforeChange TABLE

    -- If is insert
    -- BEGIN
    --     @tableAfterChange = inserted
    -- END
    -- ELSE if is delete
    -- BEGIN
    --        @tableAfterChange = deleted
    --  END
    --ELSE
    --BEGIN
    --       Else if is update
    -- @tableAfterChange = updated
    --END

    EXEC dbo.myProcedure @tableBeforeChange, @tableBeforeChange
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like the below provided your stored procedure parameters should be declared as table valued parameters.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [schema].[myTable_myTrigger] ON [schema].[myTable]
AFTER INSERT
    ,UPDATE
    ,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tableAfterChange TABLE (
        COL1 DATATYPE
        ,COL2 DATATYPE
        ,...
        )
    DECLARE @tableBeforeChange TABLE (
        COL1 DATATYPE
        ,COL2 DATATYPE
        ,...
        )

    INSERT @tableBeforeChange
    SELECT *
    FROM DELETED

    INSERT @tableAfterChange
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED

    EXEC dbo.myProcedure @tableBeforeChange
        ,@tableBeforeChange
END
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway of doing it without knowing the table structure before hand ?

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is on specific table which [myTable] in your example.  You can get the table structure because you are creating trigger on that table.  My understanding is that you do want to capture data before change and data after change of [myTable]

Comment: Thanks, I want to add this trigger to all tables in the db, hence i wont know the structure before hand. I have updated the question. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @fox909a, what you want to do with the tables '@tableBeforeChange' and '@tableAfterChange' in the dbo.myProcedure?